# Steam does not create system starters for some games

Tags: games, steam, installed-programs

For some games I installed, steam hasn't created system starters. So I can't access them from the system software menu, and I can't search for them in the program search. How can I force Steam to create these launchers?

As proposed I started steam from the terminal, the output is shown below. I tried to create a shortcut for a game that already had won, and then the following message came: "A shortcut has been created and placed on your desktop". Wen I then wanted to create a shortcut for a game that had none, the message was: "Could not create shortcut. A shortcut to this game is probably already on the desktop.

Here's the output of the terminal:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1364601080_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1364601080_client)
unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"

(steam:3247): Gtk-WARNING **: Im Modulpfad »adwaita« konnte keine Themen-Engine gefunden werden,
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:989: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1364601080_client)
[0416/155018:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(646)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1364601080_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1364601080_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1364601080_client)
Process 3247 created /ampa-ValveIPCSharedObjects3
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1364601080_client)
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49,15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 384x256, total string texture memory is 442,37 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1364601080_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1364601080_client)
Adding license for package 0
Adding license for package 64
Adding license for package 110
Adding license for package 242
Adding license for package 2275
Adding license for package 2529
roaming config store loaded successfully - 448 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
ExecCommandLine: "/home/ampa/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam"
`menu_proxy_module_load': /home/ampa/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

(steam:3247): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)

Generating new string page texture 71: 1024x256, total string texture memory is 1,49 MB
Generating new string page texture 72: 128x256, total string texture memory is 131,07 KB
Generating new string page texture 73: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1,62 MB
Generating new string page texture 74: 256x256, total string texture memory is 1,88 MB
Generating new string page texture 75: 32x256, total string texture memory is 1,92 MB
Generating new string page texture 76: 64x256, total string texture memory is 1,98 MB

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:3247): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1364601080_client)
System startup time: 38,23 seconds
Generating new string page texture 79: 24x256, total string texture memory is 2,01 MB
Generating new string page texture 80: 128x256, total string texture memory is 2,14 MB
Generating new string page texture 81: 8x256, total string texture memory is 2,15 MB
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/ampa/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
CAPIJobRequestUserStats - Server response failed 2
ExecCommandLine: "/home/ampa/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam steam://open/driverhelperready"
ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/driverhelperready"
Generating new string page texture 88: 512x256, total string texture memory is 2,67 MB
Generating new string page texture 91: 128x256, total string texture memory is 2,80 MB
Generating new string page texture 93: 256x256, total string texture memory is 3,06 MB
Generating new string page texture 96: 16x256, total string texture memory is 3,08 MB
Generating new string page texture 97: 256x256, total string texture memory is 3,34 MB
Generating new string page texture 112: 48x256, total string texture memory is 3,39 MB
Generating new string page texture 95: 128x256, total string texture memory is 3,52 MB
unlinked 2 orphaned pipes
CAsyncIOManager: 0 threads terminating.  0 reads, 0 writes, 0 deferrals.
CAsyncIOManager: 368113 single object sleeps, 0 multi object sleeps
CAsyncIOManager: 0 single object alertable sleeps, 7 multi object alertable sleeps
[2013-04-16 15:50:14] Startup - updater built Mar 29 2013 11:40:39
[2013-04-16 15:50:14] Verifying installation...
[2013-04-16 15:50:15] Verification complete
Shutting down. . .
[2013-04-16 15:56:48] Shutdown
```

PS: I think that me, you and steam have a different understanding of "shortcut". What I mean by this is not a shortcut on the desktop, but an application shortcut in the system, which enables me to search games or to start them from the menu.

I have this problem with 2 Games, darwinia and uplink. I installed 8 Games with steam.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I've noticed that your post did not include an actual question, so I've added when I assume to be the question. If it is not, please edit your post to include the question you mean to ask. I'd also recommend you contact Valve and file a bug regardingthis.

Comment: You were right, this was my question. I already asked the Question to steam support, but no one answered.

Comment: Steam support might get back to you but it may take a couple of days, however don't expect much.  They don't seem to do much research to answer just give a stock answer on the go round...I had a problem(was a bug it turned out) and said that I have already tried X,Y,Z and that it didn't work, I got back a link to a web page that told me to do what I already had, it took a second email saying that as stated in my prior email I had already tried this method to get an answer that a new client was being released to fix this bug...

Comment: If by support you mean the forums, not sure how many people use Ubuntu on the Community forums, so not sure what kind of help you will get there.  While I'm not sure that this is truly an on topic question(I think this is likely a Steam issue) I answered below, hope it works.

Comment: I guess I'm not going to be of any help to you, I don't see any problems in the terminal output, but then I'm no expert so I may have missed something.  I have been unable to recreate your problem on my system(I'm using 12.04 but this shouldn't matter but maybe...) I'm thinking maybe this is a bug with the particular game.  BTW I know what you wanted, the method worked for me to create a launcher that you could find from your dash(menu) so if you could have created a desktop shortcut, dragging it into the folder I mentioned puts it on the dash.

Comment: one last thing you might try is to verify the local files, go the the "Properties" window for the game like you did before and then click on the "Local Files" tab then select "Verify Integrity of Game Cache".  I it will then check the files(you need to be online for this).  Not sure it will work but if the files are not verified you cannot backup the games so make it will affect the shortcut creation as well.  I wish I could be more help but I'm at a total loss, this has to be a Steam issue and Steam is so new on Linux most of the problems are self serve so to speak.

Comment: I have 8 Games installed with steam and I have this problem with 2 of them, darwinia and uplink. With both, when I clicked on "Create Desktop Shortcut" under properties, I got the message, that there already is one. But theres none. So I don't think it's a game bug. Anyway, thanks for trying to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually by finding the executable binary file in your steam directory using a file browser.

The default steam directory is usually in: ~/.local/share/Steam

You should be able to find your game data in the 'steamapps' folder.

Most file browsers will let you right click on the binary and select "Create Shortcut". After you do this, move the shortcut wherever you want.

If you want to add the file to a launcher, here's some amazingly well written information on doing it in both Gnome and Unity after you find the executable's location:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what games you are having problems with, I have not heard of any that have this problem.

I installed a game but unselected the "create system application icon" and "create desktop shortcut" but decided that I wanted a launcher after wards, the way I did it *may* work for you.

First thing, in the future make sure that the box to **"create system application icon"** is checked before you install just in case it is being unselected by some Steam bug when installing. This may prevent the problem form happening with future installs.

[image]

If this fails or in your current case there is [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/66918/65969) question about how to create a system launcher for a program, this may be difficult with Steam as the launch command can be a bit convoluted and not easy to find the correct one, I only include it here so that you can see how you can do it if you ever need to for other programs and for academic value.

Back to how I created mine after the fact....

1. For the game you are trying to create a launcher for, you will need to right-click on the **Game name** if using the "detailed view" (this is the default) or on the **Game Icon** if using either the "list" or "grid" view.
2. Select **Properties**
3. Click on the box to create a **Desktop Shortcut** on the screen shot below my mouse pointer is hovering over it.

[image]

Then open a Nautilus(Home Folder) window and then press **Ctrl + H** to show hidden files then go to the following location;  `.local/share/applications`  you can then drag the icon from the desktop to the folder.

You should then have the launcher in the dash but you may have to log out and then back in to see it.

NOTE: this method will only work for your user account not any other accounts on your computer but can be repeated for each account. You could also leave it on your desktop instead of dragging it to the mentioned folder but it will not be shown in your dash.  Finally, this will also move the desktop shortcut off the desktop and into the folder but you can repeat the process if you want a desktop shortcut as well.

Comment: When I clicked on "Create Desktop Shortcut" the following message came: "Could not create shortcut. A shortcut to this game is probably already on the desktop". But there really is none.

Comment: hmm, well when testing all my games I found 2 that failed, but if I tried again it created them, not sure what problems you are having.   You can try starting Steam for a terminal by typing `steam` it will give you a lot of info but most of that can be ignored, watch and see what it say in the terminal at the moment when you try to create a shortcut, and then see what happens when you create one with a game that is working properly this may help to determine what is going wrong. You can safely delete any unwanted shortcut from your desktop when done.

Comment: I will include the description of what happened in the question, not in the comment. Is that right?